# Задача динамического программирования "Золотая пирамида"

Tags: python, динамическое-программирование, маршрут

У меня есть задание, которое нужно выполнить используя динамическое программирование. Звучит так:
В треугольнике из чисел

```
7
3 8
8 1 0
2 7 4 4
4 5 2 6 5
```

необходимо построить маршрут от вершины к основанию двигаясь только по диагонали, при этом ***найти наибольшую и наименьшую сумму чисел*** на этом маршруте и так для каждой вершины треугольника.
В интернете нашел только построение маршрута,

```
def golden_pyramid_d(triangle):
    tr = [row[:] for row in triangle]  # copy
    for i in range(len(tr) - 2, -1, -1):
        for j in range(i + 1):
            tr[i][j] += max(tr[i + 1][j], tr[i + 1][j + 1])
    return tr[0][0]
```

но мне нужно построить маршрут ТОЛЬКО по диагонали и для каждой из вершин. Как можно реализовать это на Python? Заранее благодарю за ответ!

Comment: Я не понял задание.

Comment: https://tproger.ru/problems/golden-pyramid/